# collect data from dynamic table html to json in pure js

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I need help collecting data from a table, I have a dynamic table that adds a row from the selected item in the `<select>` tag, the row is created with the following parameters

```
function addRow(selectAnswer) {
 const empTab = document.getElementById('empTable');
 let rowCnt = empTab.rows.length;
 let tr = empTab.insertRow(rowCnt); 
 for (let c = 0; c < HeaderTable.length; c++) {
  let td = document.createElement('td'); 
  td = tr.insertCell(c);
  if (c == 0) {
   let button = document.createElement('button');
   button.textContent = "Удалить";
   button.setAttribute('id', selectAnswer);
   button.setAttribute("class", "clearBtn")
   button.setAttribute("onclick", "addSelect(this)")
   td.appendChild(button);
} else if (c == 1) {
   let ele = document.createElement('span');
   ele.textContent = selectAnswer
   td.appendChild(ele);
} else {
   let ele1 = document.createElement("input");
   ele1.setAttribute("type", "number")
   td.appendChild(ele1)
  };
 }
}
```

when you click on the Calculation button, each line should be collected in JSON and sent further,

I collect data as follows

```
let btn = document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
 let database = []
 const table = document.getElementById("empTable")
  for (let i = 1; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   database.push({ name: row.cells[1], massa: row.cells[2], W: row.cells[3], A: row.cells[4] })
 }
     console.log(database)
     calck(database)
 })
```

as a result I get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvMOt.png)

but I cannot figure out how to collect the title from the `span` and all the values from the `input`, and not the cells (`td`) from the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are returning `td`, it means you have firstly to access the attribute `firstChild`. From here, you should get either the `value` (from an `input` tag) or the `innerText` (from the `span`). Note that these `slice(1)` serve to remove position 0 from arrays. Take a look:

```js
const keys = ["name","massa","W","A"]
const table = document.getElementById("empTable")
let database = [];

const fillDatabase = () => {
  let getTdContent = (td) => (td.firstChild.value || td.firstChild.innerText);
  [...table.rows]
    .slice(1)
    .forEach(row => {
      let obj = {};
      [...row.cells]
        .slice(1)
        .forEach((td,index) => obj[keys[index]] = getTdContent(td))
      database.push(obj)
    })
}

const input = document.querySelector('#input')
input.onclick = () => {
  fillDatabase();
  console.log(database);
  database = []
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <table id="empTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Название</th>
        <th>Масса,Т</th>
        <th>Влажность</th>
        <th>Зольность</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button id="Тестиль" class="clearBtn" onclick="addSelect(this)">Удалить</button></td>
        <td><span>Тестиль</span></td>
        <td><input type="number"></td>
        <td><input type="number"></td>
        <td><input type="number"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<input id='input' type='submit' placeholder='Calculate'>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, your solution is correct too, but i found a way to simplify
`
let btn = document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let database = []
  const table = document.getElementById("empTable")
  for (let i = 1; (row = table.rows[i]); i++) {
    database.push({
      name: row.cells[1].innerText,
      massa: row.cells[2].querySelector('input').value,
      W: row.cells[3].querySelector('input').value,
      A: row.cells[4].querySelector('input').value
    });
  }
  console.log(database)
  calck(database)
})
`